# simple gallery script but hard to find? please guys need help!

Tags: software-recommendation

Ok so I have come to this problem before but with no solution, so now I will ask the question.
Have you not come to the moment were you make the site for a client and then as it comes to the gallery he says " I want to upload pictures miself!" Witch is quite easy if they did not want a nice design!

So the question:

I am looking for a gallery script, in witch the client can upload photos himself. but:

1. It should just upload photos to were i want. Exapmle - I have made the gallery page and formated the div in witch the images will be. He should just select the photos upload them and they will appear in this div formated as i have done it.
2. Nothing fancy a simple lightbox script will do it. The gallery will be simple thumbnail (withc css) and the click will zoom them with the option of next/prev
3. NOT a whole page. Really I Have found many php script that will do the work but they are whole pages can not be added to a simple div.

So basicly this is it! If someone can help me I will be really really gratefull and buy them a beer.

Comment: Are you familiar with php? You can easily write something to read all files in a directory and display them.

Comment: This isn't a graphic design question. Voting to close.

Comment: @Svetoslav Welcome to GD.  This question is off-topic per our [FAQ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq)  Questions about scripts are better suited to [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) though this question may be off-topic there as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is much more of a http://www.stackoverflow.com question than a [graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) question.

I don't believe you'll find anything prepackaged.

Writing something like this with PHP isn't really that difficult.

In fact here's a php script I wrote years ago which displays files in the same directory as the script (ignoring .htm and .php files):

```
<?php
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$handle = opendir($dir);
$count = 0;
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ((strpos($entry, '.php') !== false) || (strpos($entry, '.htm') !== false)) { /* wont show .htm or .php files */ } else {
        if ($entry!=='.' && $entry!=='..' && $entry!=='.DS_Store') {
        $ent[$count] = $entry;
        $count++;
        }
    }
}
sort($ent); 

$listit = '';
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
          //load variable with data
    $listit .= '<div class="imageholder"><img src="'.$ent[$i].'" /></div>';
    }

    // spit it out
echo $listit;
?>
```

You'd just need to upload all images to the directory.

From my experience though, a client may state they "only want to upload images" but in reality, they'll want to completely manage the images, titles, sort order, etc. Most often it's easier to find something like 4images or coppermine and skin it to match your site framework. That is unless your'e prepared to create an entier database driven solution with a secure admin area.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need is a PHP script that can detect all images within a certain directory (the folder that your client can upload to) and echo them into your div, from which point Lightbox can do the rest. If you know PHP this should be relatively simple to do. Otherwise, just search for something along the lines of `PHP Image Directory Search Script`.